# Create custom email subject

Tags: webforms

So, I know how to use the tokens from the webforms to add them to the subject of the email confirmation that is sent out, but I am wondering if it is possible to automatically include the user's actual username in the subject line?

The customer I'm working with doesn't need the contact name in the very long webform they have setup because they are already set so that when someone creates their own user account, it includes all of those fields, which will save to their account, which we have configured to automatically assign them a specific role once they have completed the first step.

It's kind of repetitive to request that information again and the second webform, so that's why I'm wondering if it's possible to either include the username OR include the first and last name from their user account in the custom email subject when webforms are sent.

I've looked through quite a bit of possible answers, but they just don't seem to really cover anything other than including any of the fields/components that are actually included in the webform itself.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

If you need further information, just let me know. :)

Thank You!
Nicole

Comment: Drupal version? 7 or 8?

Comment: Currently using Drupal 7 for this one